# add jquery stellar plugin to laravel 5.4 project using mix

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, laravel-5, laravel-mix

I am new using Laravel Mix, I cant' add the jquery library stellar, it show me this error, when I try **npm run dev**:
This dependency was not found:
* jquery.stellar in ./resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js

But I already installed it using **npm install --save jquery.stellar** or **npm install jquery.stellar**

this is my webpack file:
webpack.mix.js:

```
const { mix } = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   ;
```

app.js:

```
/**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */

require('./bootstrap');

/*Ie10 windows phone fix*/
(function() {
  if (navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile\/10\.0/)) {
    var msViewportStyle = document.createElement("style");
    msViewportStyle.appendChild(
      document.createTextNode("@-ms-viewport{width:auto!important}")
    );
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(msViewportStyle);
  }
})();


/*Android fix*/
$(function () {
  var nua = navigator.userAgent
  var isAndroid = (nua.indexOf('Mozilla/5.0') > -1 && nua.indexOf('Android ') > -1 && nua.indexOf('AppleWebKit') > -1 && nua.indexOf('Chrome') === -1)
  if (isAndroid) {
    $('select.form-control').removeClass('form-control').css('width', '100%')
  }
});

/*my code*/
$(document).ready(function () {                

    $('.navbar-toggle').click(function () {
        $('.row-offcanvas').toggleClass('active');
    });        

    var w = $(window);
    if (w.width() >= 768 ){
        $('body').removeClass('margin-body');
        $('nav[role="navigation"]').removeClass('navbar-fixed-top');        
    }else{
        $('body').addClass('margin-body');
        $('nav[role="navigation"]').addClass('navbar-fixed-top');        
    }          

    $(window).stellar();    

});
```

bootstrap.js

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

require('jquery.stellar');

require('bootstrap-less');
```

And in my node_modules directory there is a jquery.stellar directory with 3 files in it: README.md,jquery.stellar.js, package.js

I dont know what is happening, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can add jquery.stellar!

Assuming that you already installed stellar as your dependency
You just have to write this line `require( 'jquery.stellar/jquery.stellar' );` 
or `require( 'jquery.stellar/jquery.stellar.js' );` both works fine